# Run KVM guest from tty

Tags: kvm-virtualization, tty

I would like to run a KVM guest from a `tty` without any X server or graphical elements running.

- What command do I use to do this if it's possible?
- Will running the command give different results in Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server?
- How would I exit from the guest once it's running?

**NB** I actually want to add an entry in the login menu to take me to the aforementioned guest, but I am planning to ask about that in a separate question. Please take this note into consideration if it affects anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the guest using `virsh`, by simply running `virsh start vmname` where `vmname` matches the output from `virsh list --all`. All this does is actually start the machine, it does not connect you to it in any way.

The only way to do that would be through VNC/Serial/SSH, but all of these are configured at guest-level. You can try virsh console vmname, but I have never used this myself, so cannot vouch for its effectiveness. See also [these Ubuntu instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Access).