# Add entry to login user menu to directly execute command

Tags: lightdm

I want to add an entry to my login menu to execute and run a program with whatever parameter I specify. I'm vaguely aware it is possible, but not quite sure how.

As a side note, I want to specifically [do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380527/run-kvm-guest-from-tty) with the entry.